# Location.getLongitude() null object reference

Tags: java, android

im creating a small mobile app that should allow me to find my current location on google maps.
I had it working earlier i was able to click on one of the buttons and it zoomed into my current location.
Now for some reason im getting the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
```

it points towards line 53 of my code which is posted below:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        double myLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        double myLatitude  = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLongitude, myLatitude);

        Marker me = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude))
                .title("Im here!")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.people))
        );
        // Zoom into my current location
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude), 15.0f));
    }

}
```

Line 53 refers to : `double myLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();`

No idea why this is happening
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` can return null, as described in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)).

In your code, you're getting a `NullPointerException` because in line 53, `myLocation` is null.